# I'm an artist/writer and I need to know if this name is okay?

Tags: characters, cantonese, names, surnames

(Apologies if the question is inappropriate I did try and find an answer myself but I kept being lead back here to ask)
I'm creating a Chinese character with the Cantonese dialect and I've named her **劉安梦 (LAU ān mèng)** and I need to know if it's okay, I've searched around but I don't know any form of Chinese and I'm trying to do this right.

If you could leave feedback on both the characters used and the name as a whole it would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you come up with that name then?

Answer (score 1):

劉安梦 is a good Chinese name, and sound's like a girl's name.

安 means steady or peaceful.

梦 means dream.

So 安梦 means steady dream or peaceful dream.

Answer (score 1):

劉安梦 in Cantonese (jyutping) is

lau4 on1 mung6

The way you have it in your original post 劉安梦 /LAU ān mèng/ seems unnatural because the family name is in Cantonese and given names in Mandarin (pinyin). If I were you, I would do the whole name in Cantonese.

The name itself sounds fine, and rather poetic, to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand Cantonese, but I understand Chinese because of I'm Chinese.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8A%89#Chinese

[image]

I think more people in mainland China recognize the name "刘" than "劉" nowadays.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8A%89#Definitions

[image]

Now we (Chinese) say Liu Shaoqi(Chinese revolutionary, politician and theorist)'s surname is 刘, rather than 劉. And say Liu Bang(刘邦)'s surname is 刘，rather than 劉.

So 刘安梦 could be more modernized,I suggest use 刘安梦.

Comment: The OP is creating "...a Chinese character with the Cantonese dialect..." So, the pronunciation of 劉 / 刘 has to be, or remain as, "Lau", and not the Mandarin pronunciation of "Liu", which would alter the original intention.

Comment: Hi @WayneCheah , There are two pronunciations of Cantonese, one is the traditional pronunciation(lau) used in Guangzhou and Hong Kong, and the other is the simplified pronunciation(liu) used in Taishan dialect. See my updated answer.

Comment: I am Hakka, and we actually pronounce it as "Liu" in the Hakka dialect. So, it is my contention that "Lau" is the  one and only Cantonese pronunciation. I speak Cantonese as well, and I just cannot pronounce "Liu" in Cantonese which sounds really awkward. Perhaps @Tang Ho can give it a try?

Comment: I just want to add some clarity (hopefully) to a confusing part of this post.  The character 劉 is pronounced lau in cantonese, I have not heard and cannot see any other version.  However even in cantonese speaking areas it isn't rare to romanize this cantonese last name using the mandarin pronunciation liu.  I believe this is what you mean and recommend an edit for clarity :)

Comment: Hi @WayneCheah, I don't quite understand your comment “I am Hakka, and we actually pronounce it as "Liu" in the Hakka dialect. So, it is my contention that "Lau" is the one and only Cantonese pronunciation.”.

Comment: Hi @zagrycha, It's almost the same meaning. I feel like my answer has already clarified it. Is there any need to make further changes?

Comment: @Whozcry I think its better not to use the simplified and traditional characters to represent the two pronunciations since you could technically see either combo.  Your answer makes sense to me as is now but I think some may not realize that :)

Comment: @zagrycha I think "its better not to use the simplified and traditional characters to represent the two pronunciations since you could technically see either combo" means "The name "劉"(lau) is in traditional Chinese characters, while the simplified Chinese characters spell it as "刘"(liu)." of my answer is not accurate.Is it right?

Comment: @Whozcry yes, because either one can be pronounced either way when read aloud, it only matters who is reading it :)

Comment: @zagrycha I changed my answer.